# How to display JSON array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have JSON values which is stored in php variable $string

```
    $string= '{
    "SUCCESS": [
        {
            "MESSAGE": "IMEI Service List",
            "LIST": {
                "Cable": "This is cable1",
                "Cable servers and log": {
                    "GROUPNAME": "Cable servers and log",
                    "SERVICES": {
                        "110": {
                            "SERVICEID": 995,
                            "TIME": " Minutes",
                            "Requires.MEP": "None",
                            "Requires.PRD": "None"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}';
```

I am having a problem while accessing these JSON values in php

**For php code i used this code:**

```
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

foreach($json_a[SUCCESS] as $p)
{
echo 'Message: '.$p[MESSAGE]. '</br>';
}
```

The above php code is fine **but i don't know how to display the values of 
"GROUPNAME" and "SERVICEID"  in php**

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=json_decode($string,true);


foreach ($data["SUCCESS"] as $loopdata)
{
//spaces occur in json key cable servers and log
   echo $loopdata["LIST"]["Cable servers and log"]["GROUPNAME"];
}
```

NOTE : Your json is not valid though. Below is valid

```
$string={
    "SUCCESS": [
        {
            "MESSAGE": "IMEI Service List",
            "LIST": {
                "Cable": "This is cable1",
                "Cable servers and log": {
                    "GROUPNAME": "Cable servers and log",
                    "SERVICES": {
                        "110": {
                            "SERVICEID": 995,
                            "TIME": " Minutes",
                            "Requires.MEP": "None",
                            "Requires.PRD": "None"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: now fine when you have copied answer... see your first answer :)

Comment: @ girish :It worked fine too .. I edited before you sorry :) i just added the syntax error just now after you answered

Comment: anyway FYI.. I edited the question long back. It hasnt been reviewed yet.. That JSON error

Comment: json format was correct before in question.. you have only format code section and now incorrect :D

Comment: No .. It wasn't . It had an ` ' , ],; ` etcetera at various places`

Comment: see this what's wrong http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27717112/1 see at bottom `]}';` beneath formatted json section

Answer (score 0):

First quote assos array key with `' or "` `['text']` good practice, and sometime key have space for example `[Cable servers and log]`  then without quote fatal error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'servers' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

and you can get **"GROUPNAME"** this way try this code

```
foreach($json_a['SUCCESS'] as $p)
{
   echo 'Message: '.$p['MESSAGE']. '</br>';
   echo 'GROUPNAME: '.$p['LIST']['Cable servers and log']['GROUPNAME']. '</br>';
}
```

Comment: Yes i was getting the same error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'servers' (T_STRING), expecting ']'"       Problem is fixed, thanks